# access append-query: set column to a literal for each record

Tags: ms-access

i have multiple tables containing similar records. i want to merge them into one table.
therefore i use an update query and map the fields from the various tables to the ones in my target-table. but i need to keep track from which table a record comes, so id like to add a literal "TABLE_XY" in the ORIGINALTABLE field in the resulting table to each record. but the query designer always wants a source-field. I cant just put a literal anywhere an select ORIGINALTABLE in "Append To"...

what to do? do i really have to add a NAMEOFTHISTABLE field to the original tables...?

thanks for your help!

Comment: When you state that you "can't just put a literal anywhere" this is simply not true. SELEC statements can always include literal values as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a backup copy of your database. Create a new query and switch to SQL View.  Then paste in this statement, and modify the table and field names to match yours:

```
INSERT INTO master_table (
    ORIGINALTABLE
    , field1
    , field2
    )
SELECT
    "TABLE_XY" AS ORIGINALTABLE
    , field_a
    , field_b
FROM
    TABLE_XY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Query Designer in `Design View` for an Update Query:

```
Field: ORIGINALTABLE 
Table: <tableName>, where tableName is the name of the table you are updating.
Update To: "TABLE_XY", make sure to include the quotes.
```

Using the Query Designer in `Design View` for an Append Query:

```
Field: Expr1: "TABLE_XY", where Expr1 is an alias name.
Table: <leaveBlank>
Append To: ORIGINALTABLE
```

Comment: im was using an "Append Query" to merge my tables. Ill try it with a Update query. thanks!